# Sumar los elementos anteriores de una lista para crear una nueva lista

Tags: python, array, lista, bucle-for, bucles

Lo que ocurre es que estoy intentando crear una lista a partir de una lista que ya tengo, la idea es que el elemento n de la lista sea una suma de (n + todos los elementos anteriores). Algo así:

lista=[a b c d e f g] .......................................................................................................................................................................................................
listafinal= [a a+b a+b+c a+b+c+d a+b+c+d+e a+b+c+d+e+f a+b+c+d+e+f+g]

Creo que sería usando un For, pero no se como implementarlo. Help :(

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Hice este código a ver si te funciona (igual lo documenté para que sea más entendible):

```
#Creación de las dos listas necesarios
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listaNueva = []

print(f"Lista principal: {lista}")

for i in range(len(lista)):
    #Este condicional hace la suma de los dos primeros numeros de la lista y la almacena en una variable llamada "num"
    #la cual se agrega directamente a "listaNueva" y de igual forma, esa variable se usa más adelante
    if i > 0 and i < 2:
        #"num" es la suma del primero número (aquel con indice 0) y el segundo numero (aquel con índice 1)
        num = lista[0]+lista[i]
        listaNueva.append(num)
    #este condicional elif permite que, si no se cumple la primera condicion (el primer if) pasa a este condicional en el
    #cual la variable "num" es la suma de ese mismo numero más el elemento de lista en esa iteración
    elif i >= 2:
         num = num+lista[i]
         #aqui se agrega la ultima variable "num" a la lista nueva
         listaNueva.append(num)
    else:
        #en este else se agrega el primer elemento de la lista principal en la lista nueva, ya que no hay una suma como tal
        listaNueva.append(lista[i])

print(f"Lista nueva: {listaNueva}")
```